# How can I copy an event into Plone with WebDAV?

Tags: events, plone, webdav

Is there way to copy a file into Plone with WebDAV and have Plone register it as an Event file (rather than a simple page)?

I would very much like to use Plone for it's standard CMS properties (which are brilliant) but I can't spend time programming up an application in Plone - it's way too complicated.  The "Plan" is to generate information in another system and use scripts to export it into Plone - hence copying via WebDAV would be a perfect solution if these generated files could be recognized as Events. 
If not an alternative, still using WebDAV, would be to generate and copy a python script, that uses API calls to create the events.  Though I'm not sure where to copy and what API calls to make. 
Or is there a way of importing iCal files?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the code to accomplish any end -- but by default, out-of-the-box, you need to:

1. Upload text files with the file name extension `.event` -- you can edit this in the content type registry tool in the root of your Plone site.  This tells the folder what type of item to create (an event).
2. Format you text file using RFC822-style key-value formatting (like mail headers or HTTP headers are formatted) in a text file you upload via WebDAV.  You must use IS0 8601 formatted (YYYY-MM-DDThh:ss:mmTZD) timestamps for all date/time field values.
3. If in doubt on the specifics of the last point, refer to the source code in Products.Archetypes.Marshall.RFC822Marshaller and DateTime.DateTime (zope2).
4. If you wish to customize the marshaller in use, you could write your own marshaller, and monkey-patch ATEvent to use it.  This would allow you to support upload/download of vcs/ics if you wrote the code to do so.  This is NOT the path of least resistance. YMMV, this is under-documented, and requires some serious Plone development experience.